# counter cache count based on active

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I seem to be unable to find an answer to this. I've set up a counter cache

```
 User
  belongs_to :company, counter_cache: true
```

now what I'm wondering is can I add a conditional to the counter cache. For instance, I'd like for the counter cache to be based on if `User.active?` as accounts can be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture) gem can help you do that. After adding this gem, change your code into

```
belongs_to :company  
counter_culture :company, :column_name => Proc.new {|user| user.active? ? 'users_count' : nil }
```

Comment: added  counter_culture :company, :users_count => Proc.new {|user| user.active? ? 'users_count' : nil } but it doesn't seem to update

Comment: Please do not change `:column_name`.  It's a keyword!